# selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'geckodriver' executable may have wrong permissions ON Heroku

Tags: python, selenium, heroku, geckodriver, instapy

Tried to deploy a survey bot for instagram using `InstaPY` but after adding `https://github.com/evosystem-jp/heroku-buildpack-firefox` buildpack to `Heroku` and setting `GECKODRIVER_PATH` to `/app/vendor/geckodriver` and `FIREFOX_BIN` to `/app/vendor/firefox` it throws an error.
[image]

Here's my code:

```
from instapy import InstaPy
from selenium import webdriver

import os
#Login 
session = InstaPy(username="USERNAME", password="PASSWORD",
                                geckodriver_path = os.environ.get("GECKODRIVER_PATH"), browser_executable_path=os.environ.get("FIREFOX_BIN"),
                                headless_browser = True)
    
session.login()
```

Comment: You probably should use /app/vendor/geckodriver/ instead of /app/vendor/geckodriver/geckodriver

Comment: @Fominykh Maxim Now its asking for browser binary location. How should I add it?

Comment: instead of geckodriver_path try using browser_executable_path=/app/vendor/geckodriver/geckodriver

Comment: @Fominykh Maxim That brought back the same problem. `Message: Expected browser binary location, but unable to find binary in default location, no 'moz:firefoxOptions.binary' capability provided, and no binary flag set on the command line` was the exact error last time with `/app/vendor/geckodriver`.

Answer (score 0):

Inside the InstaPy class parameters, you should explicitly add browser_executable_path.

Try the following:

```
session = InstaPy(username="USERNAME",
                  password="PASSWORD",
                  browser_executable_path=os.environ.get("GECKODRIVER_PATH"),
                  headless_browser=True)
```